# How to convert <a> tag has image URL in href to <img> tag using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, image, anchor

I have HTML contain multiple `<a>` tag that has image URL in `href` attribute. I want to convert that `<a>` to `<img>` tag and `href` attribute convert to `src` and text of anchor set in `alt` attribute of the image as shown in the bottom.

```
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/va6oM.jpg">jpg image</a>
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aCuV.png">png image</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

Should convert to

```
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/va6oM.jpg" alt="jpg image" />
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aCuV.png" alt="png image" />
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

How can I do this work?

Answer (score 0):

You should iterate each  tag.

```
$('a').each(function(i, a) {
   var src, txt;

   src = $(a).attr('src');
   txt = $(a).text(); // or .html()

   // now lets replace the <a> with <img>
   $(a).replaceWith('<img src="' + src + '" alt="' + txt + '">');
});
```

hope that this will help you

Answer (score 0):

Use a matching [attribute selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Attribute_selectors).

> **[attr$=value]**
>
> Represents an element with an attribute name of attr and  whose last
>   value is suffixed by "value".

---

```js
(function() {
  var anchors = $("[href$='.jpg'], [href$='.png']"),
    i = 0,
    len = anchors.length;

  for (i, len; i < len; i++) {
    var anchor = $(anchors[i]),
      href = anchor.attr('href'),
      text = anchor.text(),
      img = $("<img/>", {
        src: href,
        alt: text
      });
    anchor.replaceWith(img);
  }

})();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/va6oM.jpg">jpg image</a>
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/4aCuV.png">png image</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can select anchor tag contain image URL using jQuery [Attribute Ends With Selector `[name$=”value”]`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/).

```
$("a[href$='.jpg'], a[href$='.JPEG'], a[href$='.png'], a[href$='.gif']").someFunction();
```

Or using regex in [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/)

```
$("a").filter(function(){
  return this.href.match(/.(jpg|JPEG|png|gif)$/);
}).someFunction();
```

Then you need to convert selected tag to new tag using [`.replaceWith()`](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```
selectedAnchor.replaceWith(function(){
  return '<img src="'+ this.href +'" alt="'+ this.textContent +'" />';
});
```

```js
$("a").filter(function(){
  return this.href.match(/.(jpg|JPEG|png|gif)$/);
}).replaceWith(function(){
  return '<img src="'+ this.href +'" alt="'+ this.textContent +'" />';
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/EKb5k.png">png image</a>
<a href="http://stackoverflow.com">stackoverflow</a>
```